# Why do we use easytracker?

Tags: android, google-analytics

i have referred many links regarding  use of Easytracker.But i didn't get for what we really use it for .

this [link](https://analytics-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadocs/com/google/android/apps/analytics/easytracking/EasyTracker.html)

describe me that,
EasyTracker is a class designed to easy the burden of adding tracking code to your application. Simply add this class to your application and extend TrackedActivity instead of Activity for each Activity in your application.
Can anyone explain me in simple language with some  example why we want to or when we need to use it in application ?.Is it used only in mobile application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you want to know how many people use each screen in your app. Or how many users go from screen A to B, and how long they stay there. What screens most users leave at. How long each user sees each screen. How often users open your app per day. How many are seeing screen X right now. Or anything you can think of that's similar.

It's not necessary, but it can give you useful insights into how users in the real world are using your apps, that can help you improve them in the future.